# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' 2

Tags: c#

What is the error here? I am not understanding; please guide me.

Error:

[image]

My DBContext Class is

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace School.Models
{
    public class OurDBContext: DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Accounts> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Model Class is

```
namespace School.Models
{
    public class Roles
    {   
        public int RolesID { get; set; }
        public string Rolesname { get; set; }    
}
}
```

Comment: What error? Thats a red underline from intellisense. What actual error message do you get? Have you rebuilt?